# is a conditional string.join<object> from DataRow more efficient than a string.replace?

Tags: c#, string, datatable, dataset, datarow

Here's the working code I have:

```
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
DataTable positionData = myDataSet.Tables["Table"];
if (siteData.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    positionDV = string.Join<object>(", ",
        from r in siteData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>() select r[1]);
}
else
{
    positionDV = "";
}
```

The content of positionDV looks like this "14, 47, 5, , 11" etc. where there is a blank space for each NULL value in the database.

What I would like to achieve is that the values which are NULL are actually written to the string as NULL.  So the above example would look like "14, 47, 5, null, 11".

positionDV is just one string shown for brevity, in reality there are dozens per dataset, with close to 100,000 values each.

What I am looking for is a way to insert null instead of a space.  Would it be more efficient to create a conditional during the string.Join (and if so, how would I do that?), or would it be more efficient to just create the string as is and then create a separate assignment to do that like so:

```
positionDV += positionDV.replace(", ,", ", null,");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Enumerable.Select`, [`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) supports nullable types. Then you can use the conditional operator (?:) to get either the int-value as string or "null" if it's empty/null:

```
IEnumerable<int?> positionValues = myDataSet.Tables["Table"].AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<int?>(1));
IEnumerable<string> positions = positionValues 
    .Select(v => v.HasValue ? v.Value.ToString() : "null");
string positionDV = string.Join(", ", positions);
```